# Smooth scrolling behavior on Elements

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, parallax

Hello people I have found on this page (https://www.couleecreative.com/) A nice effect which I would like to Eibauen on my page. And that is the scrolling verhhalte of the text and other Contenst... But I didn't figure out how to solve it. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: its just `transition-delay`

Comment: Tkanks! Works perfect for me.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of effect can be made using css property "background-attach".

There are few examples available on w3school, which can help :

https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_background-attachment_fixed